# Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID already exists

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.3.2

Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID "48" already exists.

I've checked all the advice where people have had this issue and nothing helps. There do not appear to be any duplicates in the database, not in urls, not in stock, no multiple website IDs, nothing.

I can fix it by removing the affected products from all categories.
Weirdly if I go into the category and remove the product this does not help, only if you go into the product and remove it from all categories.

I've reverted to the blank theme and disabled custom extensions.

Comment: Mmm have you tried to break at the exception where that is thrown?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your generated code and meta folder? Clear your browser and magento cache? Have you also checked out Product ID # 48?